# Perl: open files from one folder and saved the edited files in another folder

Tags: perl, file, directory

I have a folder called "input" and a folder call "output". In "input" I have several .txt files. I would need a perl script which read these files, edit them (deleting the 10 first lines) and save the new .txt files in the "output" folder. It is possible to do that with perl?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible. Start hacking, return with your code in case of problems, and you'll get help.

Comment: Better yet, don't start hacking.  Start designing an algorithm, and if you get stuck on your design come back and show where you're stuck.

Comment: I need it in Perl...

Here is my try, but it does not work:

opendir(IN,"input") || die "cannot open input file"; opendir(OUT,"output") || die "cannot open output file"; while() { print unless 1 .. 10; } close(IN); close(OUT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir IN, 'input';
my @in = grep { /^[^.]/ } readdir IN; # read all file names form dir except names started with dot
closedir IN;

for my $in (@in) {
  open IN, '<', "input/$in" || next;
  open OUT, '>', "output/$in" || die "can't open file output/$in";
  while(<IN>) { #read file line by line
    print OUT $_ if $. > 10; #print the last line $_ to the file if line number $. is bigger than 10 
  }
  close OUT;
  close IN;
}
```

Comment: Thank you vey much, alex. It works perfectly. It would be too much if you explain to me the logic behind this script to learn for the future?

Comment: @user3240622 I've added comments to the code

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use Perl?

`tail -n +N` will output a file starting at line N, so if you want to remove the first 10 lines you can use `tail -n +11 file > new_file`.

To automate for all files in a folder, how about this bash one-liner:

```
for i in input/*.txt; do e=`basename $i`; tail -n +11 $i > output/${e}; done
```

**Edit**: Use modern notation `tail -n +N` instead of older [deprecated syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Old-tail-plus-N-syntax-now-fails)

Comment: Not all systems have `basename`, prefer: `cd input; for i in *.txt; do tail -n +11 "$i" > ../output/"$i"; done`